# Add bias output in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm solving a multi-class image classification problem. Training a CNN directly did not give good results for the task, so I'm now attempting a workaround. The idea is to train multiple binary classification networks, one for each image class, and then to merge their outputs. The output layer of the merged model should be a vector of N+1 elements, where N is the number of image classes. The argmax of the output vector is the classification result (image class). The first element of the output vector is a bias term that is only activated if the image fits in none of the classes with high probability. This element is going to have a constant (bias) value in the output vector, which will serve as a  classification confidence threshold.

I managed to do what I want by adding another input to the network; this input is initialized to a constant value and serves as the bias. Is it possible to what I want without changing the input shape of the network, by somehow embedding the constant value in the network itself?

This is my code so far:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(240, 320), name="img_input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)

outputs1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
outputs2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

bias = Input(shape=(1,), name="bias_input")
merged = Concatenate()([bias, outputs1, outputs2])
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, bias], outputs=merged)

print(model.summary())
plot_model(model, to_file='network.png', show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Testing the model:

```
data = np.ones(320 * 240).reshape((1, 240, 320))
bias = (np.ones(1) / 2.0).reshape((1, 1)) # use 1.0/2 as the bias value
# prints [[0.5 1.  1. ]] as expected
print(model.predict({"img_input": data, "bias_input": bias}))
```

Comment: I assume that `Dense(1,activation="softmax")` is just a simplification. Applying softmax on 1 class does not make sense.

Comment: @Lescurel is correct. Probably you should `activation='sigmoid'` so that it outputs a value in `( 0 , 1 )`

Comment: @Lescurel  thanks, that was a leftover from the multi-class network, I changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a constant value in your model definition:

```
bias_value = 0.5
bias = tf.ones((tf.shape(outputs1)[0],1))*bias_value
merged = Concatenate()([bias, outputs1, outputs2])
```

`tf.shape(outputs1)[0]` ensures that the batch shape of `bias` is compatible with the other outputs to be merged.

You also need to update the model construction, as the bias input does not exist anymore.

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=merged)
```

Running the model with your sample data gives:

```
>>> model(data)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.5, 1. , 1. ]], dtype=float32)>
```